# Proof, that $ \prod_{i = 1}^{n-1} (1 + \frac{1}{i})^i = \frac{n^n}{n!} $

Tags: combinatorics, proof-writing, induction

I want to prove the following equation: $ \prod_{i = 1}^{n-1} (1 + \frac{1}{i})^i = \frac{n^n}{n!} $

There should be an inductive way and a direct way to prove this for $ n \geq 2 $. I have absolutely no clue how to prove this in a direct manner. However, for the inductive method I got as far as to prove that it's true for $n=2$. But showing that it's true for "n+1" if it's true for any n is a problem for me too. I got as far as that using the binomial theorem:

$ \sum_{i=0}^{n} \frac{n!n^i}{i!(n - i)!} = \sum_{i=0}^{n} \frac{n! \cdot n^n}{i!(n - i)!n^i} $

But I don't see why this equation would be true. If someone could tell me the name of this formula so I can look it up or help me doing the inductive prove I would really appreciate it. Also a hint towards how this could be proved directly would help me a lot. Thanks in advance!

Comment: The formula is wrong. It should be $\frac {(n+1)^{n}} {n!}$ on the right side.  It is also a kind of  telescoping product so the proof is very simple. Binomial Theorem not needed.

Comment: @geetha290krm sorry, had a typo there. I corrected it now. How would you prove it? I'm pretty new to math if you will, so I never heard of telescoping products. Is there a certain strategy for proving this kind of equations?

Comment: If you just write out LHS for, say, $n=2$ and $n=3$ you will see how easy it is. Remember to write $1+\frac 1 i$ as $\frac {i+1}i$.

Comment: @geetha290krm sorry, I still don't get it.

Comment: @Hebol Just try to replace $i$ by $1$ and do the same for  $i = 2$ and then multiply the two terms obtained (don't forget to  use the tip provided by geetha). You should see the "telescoping product".

Comment: @coboy I see that it makes total sense for $n=2$, but for $n=3$ I don't see it anymore.

Comment: @coboy Ok, never mind, I saw it now, don't know what's wrong with me rn x)
Thanks for the help, guys!

Comment: @Hebol You're welcome !

Comment: @AnneBauval yes, thanks a lot! How do you people find that? When I use latex syntax to search on google or something i never find anything. If one variable is named differently or I have some spaces or whatever it never finds another similar question.

Comment: https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%20%5Cprod_%7Bi%20%3D%201%7D%5E%7Bn-1%7D%20(1%20%2B%20%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7Bi%7D)%5Ei%24&p=1

Comment: thank you so, so much @AnneBauval! :)